# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' during two way data binding in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-forms

I am comparatively new in angular 2.

I am trying to use 2 way data binding in a form like this-

**Model** like this-

```
export interface Profile
{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    dob: string;
};
```

**Template** like this-

```
<form action="profile">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"    ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="profileToAdd.name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob">Date Of birth:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="profileToAdd.dob">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="reset"                    >Reset</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info"    (click)="addProfileSubmit($event)" >Add Profile</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and **Component** like this-

```
'use strict';

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Profile } from '../../dataModel/Profile.ts';   //Data Model
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ProfileListComponent
    ]
})

@Component({
    selector: 'profile-list',
    template: require('./profileList.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./profileList.component.css')]
})

export class ProfileListComponent
{

    private profileToAdd: Profile;         //Current Profile to add from pop up

    ..........
    ..........

    public addProfileSubmit(event): void
    {
        console.log(this.profileToAdd);
        ..........
        ..........
    }
}
```

I am getting error like this-

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. (" <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" ngDefaultControl [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="profileToAdd.name">
</div>
<div class="form-gr"): t@52:109
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. (" <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" ngDefaultControl [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="profileToAdd.dob">
</div>
</div>
"): t@56:109
at TemplateParser.parse (D:\ProfileManagement\ProfileManagement\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:8530:21)
at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (D:\ProfileManagement\ProfileManagement\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16905:53)
at D:\ProfileManagement\ProfileManagement\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16828:85
at Set.forEach (native)
at compile (D:\ProfileManagement\ProfileManagement\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16828:49)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (D:\ProfileManagement\ProfileManagement\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:232:26)
at Zone.run (D:\ProfileManagement\ProfileManagement\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:114:43)
at D:\ProfileManagement\ProfileManagement\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:502:57
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\ProfileManagement\ProfileManagement\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:265:35)
at Zone.runTask (D:\ProfileManagement\ProfileManagement\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:154:47)
```

### Re-

My Current code is uploaded here-

https://github.com/abrarjahin/Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App/tree/master/ProfileManagement/ClientApp/app/components/profile-list

---

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Have you try to add import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; and import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms'; in to app.module.ts?

Comment: You need to import `FormsModule` in your main module not in your component

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `FormsModule` import in your module:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        FormsModule,
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
        ProfileListComponent,
        ...
    ]
})
```

`NgModel` directive is part of `FormsModule`, thus the need to import it. You can read more about `NgModel` directive [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html).

Comment: thanks for your help friend, but it is not working, I am getting the same error still now, I am updating the question in 1 min

Comment: @AbrarJahin Post your module please. (the one where `ProfileListComponent` is declared)

Comment: It is added friend

Comment: @AbrarJahin This should work. Are you sure the changes you made are registered in browser? Try to empty cache and refresh page and also check if your compiler is on.

Comment: I have done it friend, my total code is given in this github repo - https://github.com/abrarjahin/Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App/tree/master/ProfileManagement/ClientApp/app/components/profile-list

can you please help me by checking?

Comment: Try to add in app.module.ts, you haven't added.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are not "Newing up" a new instance of your interface. and setting the values of the new profile to that new instance of the interface. Also I am not familiar with interface, I changed it to an `export class`.

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input [(ngModel)]="id" />
      <button (click)="add()">add</button>

      <h1>{{newProfile.id}}</h1> 



    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  id: number;
  public newProfile : Profile = new Profile();

  constructor() {

  }

  add(){
    this.newProfile.id = this.id;
    console.log(this.newProfile.id);

  }

}
```

**here is the Model imported**

```
export class Profile

{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    dob: string;
     constructor() {
    }
};
```

Here is a working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/D9UO9Pzx2NjJKlheWxSO?p=preview

Comment: I am also getting same error by using this bro, can u please check my github repo for full code, please?

Comment: I Can walk you through everything, you are probably just missing a few small things. your code needs to be updated with the changes so I can look over it and see if you are missing anything